# Pointfree case of

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I have this code:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad
import Control.Arrow
import Text.Read

... IO (Maybe String) ...
    >>= \m -> case m of
        Just x -> putStrLn x
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Error"
```

Is it possible to make it pointfree (get rid of the `\m ->`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways. In this particular case:

```
putStrLn . fromMaybe "Error"
```

But this is a pretty special case. Slightly less special would be to use the `Maybe` catamorphism:

```
maybe (putStrLn "Error") putStrLn
```

Many types in Haskell come with a similar catamorphism that can be used to avoid `case`. But the most general case is to use the special language extension known as `LambdaCase`, which lets you write

```
\case
    Just x  -> putStrLn x
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Error"
```

Unlike `fromMaybe` (which is special to `Maybe` and the regularity of the cases used here) or the catamorphism (which is special to types that provide one), this can be used to anonymize any pattern-matching lambda.